# Mocking modules from boto in python

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, patch, boto

I am trying to write a unit test for a class that looks like below.

```
import boto
class ToBeTested:
    def location(self, eb):
        return eb.create_storage_location() 

    def some_method(self):
        eb = boto.beanstalk.connect_to_region(region, access_key, secret_key)
        location(eb)
```

Is there a way to mock **boto.beanstalk.connect_to_region** return value and finally mocking **create_storage_location**? I am new to patch and mock in python, so I have no idea how could I go about doing that. Could someone please let me know if there is a way to do this?

Thanks much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The idea is to patch `connect_to_region()` so that it returns a `Mock` object, then you can define whatever methods you want on the mock, example:

```
import unittest

from mock import patch, Mock


class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    @patch('boto.beanstalk.connect_to_region')
    def test_boto(self, connect_mock):
        eb = Mock()
        eb.create_storage_location.return_value = 'test'
        connect_mock.return_value = eb

        to_be_tested = ToBeTested()
        # assertions
```

See also:

- [An Introduction to Mocking in Python](http://www.toptal.com/python/an-introduction-to-mocking-in-python)

Hope that helps.

Comment: [The moto project](https://github.com/spulec/moto) might be of interest to you, as well.